# Using SQL stored function gives invalid SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odbc, ora-00900

I'm trying to use stored function from Oracle Express database in c# application.

```
OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SILNIA",sqlConn);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OdbcParameter sqlParam = new OdbcParameter("@ReturnValue", OdbcType.Int);
sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
com.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

label1.Content = com.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value.ToString();
```

where SILNIA function (compiles without errors) is defined:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION SILNIA RETURN NUMBER IS
w NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
for i in 1..5 loop
w:=w*i;
end loop;

RETURN w;
END SILNIA;
```

On line:

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i get

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.
```

But this works works without any problems:

```
OdbcCommand sqlCom = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SILNIA() FROM DUAL", sqlConn);
label1.Content = sqlCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ExecuteNonQuery() to run a SP.  You have to do something else -- ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader

This is because ExecuteNonQuery() is designed to only work with UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements.

Comment: I've tried both OdbcDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader(); and  label1.Content = (string)com.ExecuteScalar(); instead of com.ExecuteNonQuery(); and the same error occurs.

Comment: You sure you can't run ExecuteNonQuery() for SP's?  I'm fairly confident you can call it...

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts no parameters - try this:

```
SELECT SILNIA FROM DUAL
```