# calling oracle stored procedure in c#

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a oracle stored procedure in c# like this

```
 OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand();
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "KAMRAN.ATTN";
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();

            Label3.Text = "Attendance Posted Successfully";
```

But I am showing this error

```
ERROR [42000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Please any One Can tell what exactly i am missing to call this procedure.plz help !

Comment: YES `KAMRAN` IS SCHEMA AND `ATTN` IS PROCEDURE NAME

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Oracle stored procedure from C#.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940587/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-from-c-net)

Comment: YES tried but same error

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174968/using-sql-stored-function-gives-invalid-sql-statement (but that's not solved either)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inverse the statements:

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "KAMRAN.ATTN";
```

Also, maybe try to add:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

before

```
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "KAMRAN.ATTN";
```

I think that you should also use a DataTable

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
```

Maybe that it should also be an Oracle Data Adapter:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand();
```

So you should have:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand();
da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "KAMRAN.ATTN";


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
return dt;
da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
```

I hope this helps in any way.